# German characters are displayed incorrectly with SetDlgItemText

Tags: c++, sqlite, encoding, mfc, codepages

I read a german text from an sqlite database with C++, (the text looks good with the database viewer). But when I display it in a dialog with SetDlgItemText the text looks like this (see the picture).

[image]

```
    CString strWarning(pStmt->GetColumnCString(nCol));      
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_WARNING_MESSAGE, strWarning);
```

Comment: The returned string is obviously UTF-8 encoded, and Windows functions expect either codepage-based ASCII (deprecated) or 16-bit `wchar` strings (with Unicode enabled, which may actually be a default setting today).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string looks like it's encoded as UTF-8, which Windows doesn't handle.

You'll need to convert it to UTF-16 and ensure that you're calling the wide version of `SetDlgItemText`, either by changing your project's character set option to `Use Unicode Character Set` or specifying `SetDlgItemTextW`.

You can convert your string from UTF-8 to UTF-16 with the [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: the project is unicode, I have solved the problem by calling GetColumnString16 (I use the Kompex Sqlite library) and this returns the correct string format :)

Comment: @Mario *"The project is unicode"* is of no relevance here. The problem is not about whether or not Unicode is in use, but rather whether DB and consumer agree on the same character **encoding**.